# table column hover load separate div

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring something simple out. I have a large datatable, and I want that when hovering any column, a specific div (and different for each column) is loaded somewhere on the page, outside the table.

How should I go about that? I'm having trouble defining columns (I'm using jquery dataTables), and then finding a way to load a different image for each column.

Here is my current code that doesn't take columns into account:

```
$('td').hover(function() {
    var myClass = $(this).attr("class");
    /* hide any previously loaded div */
    $(".loaded").hide();
    /* load my new div with the content I need */
    $("#"+myClass).show();
});
```

And the HTML:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="sp1">SP1</th>
        <th class="sp2">SP2</th>
        <th class="bb1">BB1</th>
        <th class="br1">BR1</th>
        <th class="br2">BR2</th>
        <th class="br3">BR3</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="sp1">xxx</td>
        <td class="sp2">xxx</td>
        <td class="bb1">xxx</td>
        <td class="br1">xxx</td>
        <td class="br2">xxx</td>
        <td class="br3">xxx</td>
    </tr>
    ....
</tbody>
```

Thanks!

Comment: can you show your current code??

Comment: here you go, sorry about that! :-)

Comment: are you using server side processing or is that a static table??

Comment: It looks okay, what happens? Do you get any errors? Also I would use `.on('hover', function() {})`

Comment: Actually, it doesn't work because it does detect the tds, but not the ths. So when I hover over a th, I doesn't trigger the event.

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if this is what you want, but check it out:

This code will show the name of the div you are hovering in another div.

https://jsfiddle.net/5jy071t5/4/

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li name="first">Hoover me</li>
  <li name="second">And me</li>
</ul>

<div id="output"></div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$( "li" ).hover(
  function() {
    $("#output").html($(this).attr("name"));
      //you can also load an image if you like
  }, function() {
    $("#output").html("");
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It works as charm. Maybe you were missing either id or class.

```js
$('td').hover(function() {
    var myClass = $(this).attr("class");
    /* hide any previously loaded div */
    $(".loaded").hide();
    /* load my new div with the content I need */
    $("#"+myClass).show();
});
```

```css
.loaded{
  display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th class="sp1">SP1</th>
        <th class="sp2">SP2</th>
        <th class="bb1">BB1</th>
        <th class="br1">BR1</th>
        <th class="br2">BR2</th>
        <th class="br3">BR3</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="sp1">xxx</td>
        <td class="sp2">xxx</td>
        <td class="bb1">xxx</td>
        <td class="br1">xxx</td>
        <td class="br2">xxx</td>
        <td class="br3">xxx</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<div id="sp1" class="loaded">sp1</div>
<div id="sp2" class="loaded">sp2</div>
<div id="bb1" class="loaded">bb1</div>
<div id="br1" class="loaded">br1</div>
<div id="br2" class="loaded">br2</div>
<div id="br3" class="loaded">br3</div>
```